# Tab delimited and ISO-8859-1 export

Tags: excel, encoding, iso-8859-1

I need to export from Excel 2016 a file into tab delimited txt with encoding ISO-8859-1, while all the special characters are kept. any idea?

Comment: I think you should ask to SuperUser (one of our sister site, see icon on top right). Your question is about excel. BTW: what about saving the file as CSV and get extra options, where you can change the codepoint.

Answer (score 0):

(Your question isn't inherently related to programming, but since there are many similar but not identical questions already existing here, I'm answering.)
You are not mentioning which OS you are working on, so I describe a platform neutral solution.
I use `pipx` for installing python tools, but I think you can substitute `pipx` for `pip` (perhaps `sudo pip`).

```
pipx install xlsx2csv
xlsx2csv --delimiter 'tab' infile.xlsx outfile.tsv
```

The default encoding is `utf-8`, but I'd be surprised if the above doesn't give you what you want. I do not have your particular version of Excel; I'm on macOS Big Sur with Excel v16.08. In my tests with norwegian characters in an Excel sheet, using `xlsx2csv --outputencoding ISO-8859-1` or `xlsx2csv --outputencoding latin-1` did not yield good results but `utf-8` (the default) does.

(from https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv)